# Get full alphabet without using letters

Tags: javascript

After seeing the following code, I started wondering if there was a way to access the full lowercase alphabet without using any letters(conditions to be applied below):

```
[($=(!0)+'')[0]+$[1]+$[2]+((!1)+'')[3]+$[0],(([]+[])[1]+'')[1]+([]+{})[1],([]+{})[1]+(([]+[])[1]+'')[1]+$[3]].join(' ');
// "trust no one"
```

Using the various statements below the following letters can be accessed `a b c d e f g i j l m n o p r s t u v x y`:

```
// "true" yeilds: e r t u
!0+'';

// "false" yeilds: a f l s
!1+'';

// "[object Object]" yeilds: b c j o t
[]+{}+'';

// "undefined" yeilds: d i n
[][1]+'';

// "Infinity" yeilds: y
1/0+'';

// Using the above statements "constructor" can be spelled
// It has no value by itself but can be coupled with other statements to get more letters
($=[]+{}+'')[5]+$[1]+(([]+[])[1]+'')[1]+((!1)+'')[3]+($=!0+'')[0]+$[1]+$[2]+($=[]+{}+'')[5]+$[6]+$[1]+((!0)+'')[1];

// "function RegExp() { [native code] }" yeilds: g p v x
(/./)[/*constructor" from above*/]+'';

// "function Number() { [native code] }" yeilds: m
(0)[/*"constructor" from above*/]+'';
```

What are ways to access to remaining characters `h q w z` with the following limits applied:

1. Only non-letter characters can be used in the code(symbols, numbers and punctuation)
2. All characters used within the code must fall into ASCII's first 128 characters
3. Code must not rely on environment variables such as `global` for node, `window` for browsers, etc
4. Reencoding letters such as using escaped variants, octlet syntax, etc should be refrained from until all other avenues have been explored.

Comment: i don't see any reason why not.

Comment: I think this question should have been asked in [codegolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) instead of stackoverflow.

Comment: I didn't know about codegolf. is there a way to move it there without closing this one, and creating a new question there?

Comment: You don't have the source of d n, etc.. broken out -- I believe you are getting that through "undefined"? `([]+[])[1]+''` ?

Comment: yes I am. It must have gotten deleted while editting. Added it back

Comment: By the way, with numbers included -- if we can find a way to get a *capital* `C` and the `h` -- game over. `''['constructor']['fromCharCode'](120)`

Comment: By the way, you can get "undefined" with fewer characters: `''+''[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha got it. If `unescape` is allowed, not encoded for clarity:

```
[]['constructor']['constructor']['call']('','return unescape' + '("%68%71%77%7' + 'a' +'")')()
```

This gives us hqwx, and can of course give us anything else.

the only bit that cannot be reached is `'("%68%71%77%7<a goes here>")'`, but that satisfies the symbols and numbers rule.  The a can be constructed otherwise.

If we want to avoid unescape, we can use `(828035)['toString'](36)` -- The "magic" number `828035` was generated by using `parseInt('hqwz',36)`.

And encoded -- with large parts broken out for readability:

```
// From your post
str_constructor = ($=[]+{}+'')[5]+$[1]+(([]+[])[1]+'')[1]+
    ((!1)+'')[3]+($=!0+'')[0]+$[1]+$[2]+($=[]+{}+'')[5]+
    $[6]+$[1]+((!0)+'')[1];

// call
str_call = ([]+{}+'')[5]+($=!1+'')[1]+$[2]+$[2];

// return unescape ( bonus, not using a literal space character )
ret_unescape = ($=!0+'')[1]+$[3]+$[0]+$[2]+$[1]+($=''[1]+'')[1]+
    ([]+{}+'')[7]+$[0]+$[1]+$[3]+($=!1+'')[3]+([]+{}+'')[5]+$[1]+
     ((/./)[str_constructor]+'')[14]+(!0+'')[3];


// finally
[][str_constructor][str_constructor][str_call]('',ret_unescape + '("%68%71%77%7' + (!1+'')[1] +'")')() // "hqwz"

// or -- toString
str_toString = (!0+'')[0]+([]+{}+'')[1]+($=(('')[str_constructor]+''))[9]+$[10]+$[11]+$[12]+$[13]+$[14]

(828035)[str_toString](36)  // hqwz
```

Bonus-bonus:

We can even ditch numbers if we are sneaky.

```
true: !![]
false: ![]

0: ![]+![]
1: !![]+![]
2: !![]+!![]
10: (!![]+![]+'')+(![]+![])
```

My big nasty magic constant could therefore be:

```
((!![]+!![])*(!![]+!![])*(!![]+!![])+'')+((!![]+!![])+'')+
    ((!![]+!![])*(!![]+!![])*(!![]+!![])+'')+
    (![]+![]+'')+(!![]+!![]+!![]+'')+((!![]+!![])*(!![]+!![])+!![])-![]
```

Comment: I'll give a point for this, but feel its a bit bending of the rules.

Comment: Which rule? I will try to find time to encode `constructor` `call` and `return unescape` when I get home today.

Comment: the `no letter` rule. I understand you didn't use any letters, but you did encode them to get around that. The goal for this was to grab the characters in un-orthodox means. - With that said this is quite the ingenious solution that does fit into the rules as stated

Comment: The only other way I can think, that avoids *obvious* encoding: `(828033).toString(36)` ( we have capital S through `"function String() { [native code] }"` -- and we can run that with my above trick ) -- that at least seems more magic.  That *was* encoded though. via `parseInt('hqwx',36)`

Comment: ... and I just realized `z` is what we are missing, not `x` -- the method still applies.

Comment: `x` isn't needed as it can be grabbed from `(/./)["constructor"]`. Unless answers for the last 4 letters pop up, you will most likely get the accepted answer

Comment: Edited to fix that, also included the `unescape`-less version in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
([]+{}+'')[5]+([]+{}+'')[1]+(([]+[])[1]+'')[1]+(!1+'')[3]+(!0+'')[0]
+(!0+'')[1]+(!0+'')[2]+([]+{}+'')[5]+(!0+'')[0]+([]+{}+'')[1]+(!0+'')[1]
```

gives you 'constructor', which you can then use with a string literal like this:

```
('')[([]+{}+'')[5]+([]+{}+'')[1]+(([]+[])[1]+'')[1]+(!1+'')[3]+(!0+'')[0]
+(!0+'')[1]+(!0+'')[2]+([]+{}+'')[5]+(!0+'')[0]+([]+{}+'')[1]+(!0+'')[1]]+''
```

which gives you `'function String() { [native code] }'` which gives you 'v' and 'g'

Edit: You found 'constructor' too, it's tricky to get much more without a way to access the global variable.

Here's a way to get the global variable in Node:

```
('')['constructor']['constructor']('','return global')()
```

Using the approaches above:

```
('')[
    // 'constructor'
    ({}+'')[5] + ({}+'')[1] + (([]+[])[1]+'')[1] + (!1+'')[3] +
    (!0+'')[0] + (!0+'')[1] + (!0+'')[2] + ({}+'')[5] +
    (!0+'')[0] + ({}+'')[1] + (!0+'')[1]
][
    // 'constructor'
    ([]+{}+'')[5] + ([]+{}+'')[1] + (([]+[])[1]+'')[1] + (!1+'')[3] +
    (!0+'')[0] + (!0+'')[1] + (!0+'')[2] + ([]+{}+'')[5] +
    (!0+'')[0] + ([]+{}+'')[1] + (!0+'')[1]
](
    '',
    // 'return'
    (!0+'')[1] + (!0+'')[3] + (!0+'')[0] + (!0+'')[2] + (!0+'')[1] + (([]+[])[1]+'')[1] +
    ' ' +
    // 'g'
    (('')[
        ([]+{}+'')[5] + ([]+{}+'')[1] + (([]+[])[1]+'')[1] +
        (!1+'')[3] + (!0+'')[0] + (!0+'')[1] + (!0+'')[2] +
        ([]+{}+'')[5] + (!0+'')[0] + ([]+{}+'')[1] + (!0+'')[1]
    ] + '')[14] +
    // 'lobal'
    (!1+'')[2] + ({}+'')[1] + ({}+'')[2] + (!1+'')[1] + (!1+'')[2]
)()
```

From there you could access `global.env` and from there it's almost cheating.

Edit: You can also build this:

```
[]['constructor']['constructor'](
    'o',
    "var a=[];for(var x in o){a.append(x)};return a")
```

Which gives you a poor man's `Object.keys()`, which you can use to access the names of various objects' methods.

You can also build an eval function & assign it to `$`:

```
$=[]['constructor']['constructor']('s','return eval(s)')
```

Comment: Nice, I forgot about 'string'

Comment: I don't/didn't know how to explain it in the OP, but I don't want to rely on grabbing info from enviornment dependant variables.

Comment: If you can just get a 'k', you can use the Function constructor to build a function that invokes Object.keys().

Comment: Also, you can get '[object Object]' with just `{}+''`, you don't need `[]+{}+''`.

Comment: `{}+''` yeilds `0` in chrome's dev console

Comment: That's funny, it works in node console. I guess it depends on which platform you're targeting. It's a bit easier in Node because you can get the global object without needing 'h' for 'this' or 'w' for 'window'.

Comment: `i=97;
var x="";
while (i < 123) {x = x + ' ' + String.fromCharCode(i);i++;}
document.write(x);`

Comment: @DMSJax We are still missing `C` and `h`, therefore cannot do that under the rules.

Comment: @Dre Sorry, guess I'm missing part of the rules/question somewhere, don't see where "C" was to be included and what i posted includes the "h"... at least it shows it does? I'll re-read post. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution to produce all English letters both in lowercase and uppercase.
This solution is not using `unescape` function but do utilize dynamic function generator to implicitly un-escape hex literal string.

```
((_,$,$$) =>
/* _ = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
   $ = code => Function( arg, code )
   declare $$ (will be defined later)
*/
_[ // invoke _.toUpperCase() ...
  // construct "toUpperCase"...
  _[19]+_[14]+ // "to"
  ($$=( // $$ = hexCode => { return `\x${hexCode}` }
    __ => $( // __ as hexCode, invoke the $ function...
      [ _[17]+_[4]+_[19]+_[20]+_[17]+_[13], // "return"
        ' `\\',_[23],__,'`'] // ` \x${hexCode}`
      [ _[9]+_[14]+_[8]+_[13] ]('') // .join('')
    )()
  ))(55)  // 'U'
  +_[15]+_[15]+_[4]+_[17]  // "pper"
  +$$(43)  // '\x43' --> 'C'
  +_[0]+_[18]+_[4] // "ase"
]() // --> "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
+_  // concatenate with the _
)(...( // call with spread operator...
  ( (_,$,$$) => [
    _[1]+_[28]+_[31]+_[11]+_[4]+_[0]  // "abcdef"
    + ( _ += // append following string to _
        ''[
            $=[ // "constructor", saved as $
              _[31]+_[27]+_[10]+_[3]+_[5]
              +_[6]+_[7]+_[31]+_[5]+_[27]+_[6]
            ]
        ] // --> "function String() { [native code] }"
        + ''+/./[$]
          // --> "function RegExp() { [native code] }"
      )[55]  // 'g'
    + (17)[
        $$=_[5]+_[27]+_[50]+_[5]+_[6]+_[21]+_[10]+_[55]
        // $$ = "toString"
      ](36)  // (17).toString(36) --> 'h'
    +_[21]+_[29]  // "ij"
    +(20)[$$](36)  // (20).toString(36) --> 'k'
    +_[2] // 'l'
    +(0[$]+'')[11] // (Number.toString())[11] --> 'm'
    +_[10]+_[27]+_[90] // "nop"
    +(26)[$$](36) // (26).toString(36) --> 'q'
    +_[6]+_[3]+_[5]+_[9]+_[66] // "rstuv"
    +(32)[$$](36) // (32).toString(36) --> 'w'
    +_[89]+_[25] // "xy"
    +(35)[$$](36) // (35).toString(36) --> 'z'
    // code=>Function(arg,code)
    , _ => (()=>{})[$]('_',_) 
  ])(
    // "falsetrueundefinedInfinity[object Object]"
    ''+![]+!![]+[][0]+(1/0)+{}
  )
));
```

Returned string: `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`.

### Explanation:

1. Generate initial string...

```js
    ''+![]+!![]+[][0]+(1/0)+{}
```

which will produce

```
"falsetrueundefinedInfinity[object Object]"
```

Let's name this string as **{s1}** for this explanation.

2. Pass string ***s1*** to closure function ***f1*** as first argument (the `_` variable)
3. Grab `"abcdef"` from ***s1*** (now stored in `_` variable)...

```js
    _[1] + _[28] + _[31] + _[11] + _[4] + _[0]
```

4. Compose `"constructor"` from ***s1*** ...

```js
    _[31]+_[27]+_[10]+_[3]+_[5]
    +_[6]+_[7]+_[31]+_[5]+_[27]+_[6]
```

and saved it into `$` variable (`$` is declared as undefined argument in ***f1*** function)

5. Get the `String` function by taking constructor of any string instance (in this case we can just use an empty string)...

```js
<string_instance>.constructor
= ''.constructor = ''['constructor']
= ''[$] // $ = "constructor" in previous step
= the String function
```

Convert it to string by appending it to an empty string to get `"function String() { [native code] }"`

6. Do the same to a `RegExp` instance...

```js
/./[$]   //--> the RegExp function
```

Convert it into a string --> `"function RegExp() { [native code] }"`

7. Do the same to a `Number` instance...

```js
0[$]   // --> the Number function
```

Convert it into a string --> `"function Number() { [native code] }"`

8. Append strings from step 5, 6 and 7 to the `_` variable.
   Let's name this new string as ***s2***. Content of ***s2*** now is...

```js
   "falsetrueundefinedInfinity[object Object]function String() { [native code] }function RegExp() { [native code] }function Number() { [native code] }"
```

9. From ***s2***, grab the character `'g'` at index #55
10. Compose `"toString"` from ***s2*** ...

```js
_[5]+_[27]+_[50]+_[5]+_[6]+_[21]+_[10]+_[55]
```

and store it into the `$$` variable (it is also declared as undefined argument in ***f1*** function)

11. Now we can call `toString()` function from any number to get any lower case letter by supplying `36` as its radix argument, thus calling `(17).toString(36)` will yield the `'h'` letter. In our code, this accomplished by: `(17)[$$](36)`
12. Next take letter `'i'` and `'j'` from ***s2***
13. Get letter `'k'` using the same `toString(36)` method as in step 11, this time with number `20`.
14. Grab `"lmnop"` from ***s2***
15. Use `(26).toString(36)` to get letter `'q'`
16. Grab `"rstuv"` from ***s2***
17. Use `(32).toString(36)` to get letter `'w'`
18. Grab `"xy"` from ***s2***
19. Use `(35).toString(36)` to get letter `'z'`.
20. Now we have all lowercase letters. Put it into ***f1***'s result array as its first element.
21. To get the uppercase letters is a little tricky. We'll use function generator (the `Function` function) to generate a function which returns character decoded from given argument. As first step, obtain the `Function` function by referencing constructor of a function instance...

```js
<function_istance>.constructor
= ( ()=>{} )[ 'constructor' ]
= (()=>{})[$]
= Function
```

and wrap it into a closure to generate our desired function...

```
code => Function( argument_name, code )
```

Because we can't use letters, just reuse the `'_'` name for its argument...

```js
_ => Function( '_', _ )
```

Please don't be confused between the `_` (argument of the closure) with the `'_'` (argument of the new function generated as the result of calling the closure).
For the sake of clarity, let's name this closure function as ***f2***.
We'll put the ***f2*** as second element in ***f1***'s result array.

22. Now ***f1*** is finished, we'll pass the result (array from the previous two steps) using spread operator as `_` and `$` argument into function ***f3***. So in ***f3***, our ***s2*** string is in `_` variable, and ***f2*** is in `$` variable.
23. Create new function ***f4***, which is to return a character from given argument. We'll need ***f4*** to produce two uppercase letters: `'U'` (char code 0x55) and `'C'` (char code 0x43). This will be accomplished by simple return statement followed by a hex-literal string `"return \x??"` where `??` is the argument to be passed on. Because we have all required letters to compose the code (all of them is lowercase letters), we just need to assemble them. Put ***f4*** as variable `$$` (it is already defined as undefined argument in ***f3***).
24. Call ***f4*** with `55` as argument (will be automatically casted into `'55'`, prefixed with hard-coded `'\x'` become `'\x55'` --> letter `'U'`.
25. Prepend with `"pper"` grabbed from ***s2***
26. Call ***f4*** again with `43` as argument, this will produce letter `'C'`.
27. Prepend with `"ase"`, thus we have `"toUpperCase"`
28. Invoke `_.toUpperCase()` to get upper case version of ***s2***
29. Prepend string from step 28 with ***s2***
30. Return from ***f3*** with result string from step 29: all letters both in lowercase and uppercase forms.